# Limit system reboot burst

Tags: systemd, services, reboot

Systemd allows to automatically restart services if they have crashed. To prevent indefinite services restart it uses @StartLimitInterval@ and @StartLimitBurst@ [variables](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#StartLimitInterval=).

Moreover, I can [reboot](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#StartLimitAction=) whole system after service restart failure (it seems reasonable in case: one OS — one service).

The problem is that if I combine those features of systemd and my service fails constantly, I get continuous reboot.

Is there way to stop rebooting PC after the first reboot? In other words, I would like to specify @StartLimitInterval@ and @StartLimitBurst@ variables but for a whole OS, not for a service.

I searched for this feature but found nothing. In the other hand I guess that somebody has solved this problem before.

I think that I can do this by creating lock file before first reboot and then watching it, but it seems ugly and I don't know how to tell systemd create it.